# AJAX POST for Contact Form returns 500 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am working in node.js and using Nodemailer. I have a contact form using AJAX, that when submitted, generates a 500 error. Below is what I am getting as a response, and the code for the form below it. I am also using csrf_token on the form. I tried removing it, but it did not help. I have tried to use GET, but I am still getting the same error. I am really stuck on this.

```
Error response: The error is happening on send @jquery-1.10.2.js:6.

send @jquery-1.10.2.js:6
x.extend.ajax @jquery-1.10.2.js:6
$.find.jqBootstrapValidation.submitSuccess  @shibui.js:82
(anonymous function) @jqBootstrapValidation.js:76
x.event.dispatch @jquery-1.10.2.js:5
v.handle @jquery-1.10.2.js:5
```

The code that handles the form is:

```
$('#contactForm').find('input,textarea').jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function(form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function(form, event) {
        toggleSubmit(form);
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour

        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val(); 
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "/contactus",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                message: message
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                showStatus(form, 'success', 'Your message has been sent.');
                //$('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                showStatus(form, 'danger', 'Sorry ' + firstName + ', it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!');
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                toggleSubmit(form);
            },
            complete: function(data) {
            },
        });
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});
```

Comment: error 500 is a server side error. The code you posted is nearly useless

Comment: So look at the error that is on the server.

Comment: Look for problems in `/contactus` server code.

Comment: Thanks for the responses and references to "How to ask". It's my first question on this forum.  I am looking at the server code, and testing. Will clarify question if I can't find anything. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
500 is an internal server error, if you're using Node it's likely some uncaught exception. You have to look at the server code to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I will do that.